# Tabris.js developer app not loading my app

Tags: tabris, tabris-js

When I try to access my app via the URL in the Tabris.js 2 Developer app, I briefly see the message below, and the app returns me back to the URL screen:

"Could not load boot.min.js or boot.js file from tabris module 'node_modules/tabris'"

I tried running the basic out-of-the-box tabris test app (using `tabris init` in an empty directory) and the same issue happened, so I am confident that this is not something to do with my app.

Some other details:

- Using v2.0.0 of tabris.js, although this is happening with 2.0.0-rc2 as well
- The last time this worked with the same code base for me was prior to my phone (a Nexus 5X) being upgraded to Android Oreo. I wonder if the Tabris.js 2  Developer app has any issues running in Oreo?
- I know that the http-server is running correctly on my development machine, as I can navigate to http://[development-ip]:8080/package.json and get that file on my mobile device

Comment: Are you certain that you're running the *exact* same version on the JS that your client app is running?

I haven't noticed any issues with Oreo, so it's probably not that.

Comment: @CookieGuru - do you mean the tabris.js version? How would I confirm which version the developer app is running?

Comment: Did you run `npm install tabris` in your project? Can you access http://[development-ip]:8080/node_modules/tabris/boot.js?

Comment: @Nick It will be in `package.lock` if you are running NPM >= 5

Comment: Thanks @CookieGuru - your comment made me look into this and I tried v2.1.0 and everything worked nicely. The post below also answers the question for those might be stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm the issue with a project created with the CLI (version 2.0). The latest tabris dev app (2.1) does not work with tabris 2.0. You'd have to upgrade your projct to tabris 2.1:

```
npm install --save tabris@^2.1.0
```

The reason is that as of tabris 2.1 a bootstrapping file (boot.js) is now read from the tabris module. This file was included in the dev app before.

When you upgrade tabris-cli to the latest version, projects created with `tabris init` will not be affected by this problem.